# Python - Pillow rounded rectangle not working

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I tried to create a rank card for my Discord Bot. But the experience bar won't round correctly.
I don't know what to do. Here's my code:

```py
def draw(self, user: str, rank: str, level: str, xp: str, needed_xp: str, profile_bytes: BytesIO) -> BytesIO:
        
        profile_bytes = Image.open(profile_bytes)
        im = Image.new('RGBA', (800, 200), (44, 44, 44, 255))

        im_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        im_draw.text((154, 5), user, font=self.font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

        rank_text = f'Rank:  #{rank}'
        im_draw.text((154, 37), rank_text, font=self.medium_font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

        xp_text = f'Level: {level}'
        im_draw.text((154, 62), xp_text, font=self.small_font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

        xp_text = f'Experience: {xp}/{needed_xp}'
        im_draw.text((154, 87), xp_text, font=self.small_font, fill=(255, 255, 255, 255))

        im_draw.rounded_rectangle((40, 180, 440, 150), fill=(64, 64, 64, 255), outline=(92, 23, 47, 255), width=3, radius=15)
        
        length = 40 + int(xp)/int(needed_xp)*400
        im_draw.rounded_rectangle((40, 180, length, 150), fill=(221, 221, 221, 255), outline=(92, 23, 47, 255), width=3, radius=15)
        
        im.paste(profile_bytes, (10, 10))

        im.show()
```

But it just created this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c7c7.jpg

The Level bar looks like it was cut off. What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have the y coordinates in the wrong order.  It tries to make the curves go down from the first Y and up from the second Y, and that produces the results you see.  Change to:

```
im_draw.rounded_rectangle((40, 150, 440, 180), ...
and
im_draw.rounded_rectangle((40, 150, length, 180), ...
```